# KnockoutJS - How to compute data from returned JSON results

Tags: json, knockout.js, getjson

I'm trying to change the way how DOB `resource.birthDate` is displayed from returned JSON

Knockout.js:

```
this.rows= ko.observableArray([]);

$.getJSON(
  "./malib/api-call.php",
  function (data) {
     self.rows(data.entry);
  }
);
```

and HTML:

```
           <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
            <tr data-bind="attr: { id: resource.id}, css: {'isSelected':$root.selPatient() == $data}, click: $parent.highlightPatient.bind($parent), event : { dblclick: $parent.selectPatient.bind($parent) }" >
                <td class="col_name" data-bind="text: resource.name[0].text"></td>
                <td class="col_dob" data-bind="text: resource.birthDate"></td>
                <td class="col_gender" data-bind="text: resource.gender"></td>
                <td class="col_address" data-bind="text: resource.address[0].line[0] + ', ' + resource.address[0].city + ' ' + resource.address[0].state + ' ' + resource.address[0].postalCode"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I have added code below to KnockoutJS part:

```
this.rows= ko.observableArray([]);

$.getJSON(
  "./malib/api-call.php",
  function (data) {
     self.rows(data.entry);

                        self.returnDOB = function(item) {

                            var nonusDOB = item.split("-");
                            return nonusDOB[2] +"/"+ nonusDOB[1] +"/"+ nonusDOB[0];
                        };  
  }
);
```

and replaced in HTML:

```
<td class="col_dob" data-bind="text: returnDOB(resource.birthDate)"></td>
```

but that solutions throws an error

`Message: returnDOB is not defined`

Any tips on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding is trying to execute your function before the function exists. You should create the function outside of the json request.

```
self.returnDOB = function(item) {
    var nonusDOB = item.split("-");
    return nonusDOB[2] +"/"+ nonusDOB[1] +"/"+ nonusDOB[0];
}; 

$.getJSON(
  "./malib/api-call.php",
  function (data) {
    self.rows(data.entry); 
  }
);
```

Comment: Still the same error `Unable to process binding "text: function (){return returnDOB(resource.birthDate) }" Message: returnDOB is not defined`

Comment: @JackTheKnife without seeing all of your code I can only guess at the structure, but since your binding is within a foreach loop it probably needs to look like `data-bind="text: $parent.returnDOB(birthDate())"`

Comment: `$parent.returnDOB(resource.birthDate)` did the job